# Variable interpolation within a ${__P()}

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to interpolate a variable inside a ${__P()} function, and have read several threads on the matter, but it isn't working. My User Defined Variables contain:

```
FALLBACK_TOKEN someLongString
ACTUAL_TOKEN ${__P(tokenSetOnCommandLine,???)}
```

Tried so far:

```
ACTUAL_TOKEN ${__P(tokenSetOnCommandLine,${FALLBACK_TOKEN})}
    // literally returns "${FALLBACK_TOKEN}" (as expected as per Jmeter docs)

ACTUAL_TOKEN ${__P(tokenSetOnCommandLine,${__V(${FALLBACK_TOKEN})})}
    // same as above

ACTUAL_TOKEN ${__P(tokenSetOnCommandLine,${__evalVar(${FALLBACK_TOKEN})})}
    // returns blank

ACTUAL_TOKEN ${__P(tokenSetOnCommandLine,${__eval(${FALLBACK_TOKEN})})}
    // literally returns "${FALLBACK_TOKEN}"

ACTUAL_TOKEN ${__P(tokenSetOnCommandLine,${__eval(FALLBACK_TOKEN)})}
    // returns "FALLBACK_TOKEN"

ACTUAL_TOKEN ${__P(tokenSetOnCommandLine,${__evalVar(FALLBACK_TOKEN})})}
    // returns blank
```

As per Jmeter docs at http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__evalVar, I would expect either `evalVar` or `eval` to work (still a little unclear on the differences, to be honest). What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Property is being populated **before** User Defined Variables value is evaluated so it won't work this way.

Options are in:

1. Hard-code the default value in the .jmx script like:

   ```
   ${__P(tokenSetOnCommandLine,something)}
   ```
2. Set default value in *user.properties* file (under JMeter's /bin folder), add the following line:

   ```
   tokenSetOnCommandLine=something
   ```

   In 2nd case if you provide `tokenSetOnCommandLine` value as command-line argument like:

   ```
   jmeter -JtokenSetOnCommandLine=somethingElse
   ```

   it will override "default" value of `something` with `somethingElse`. Otherwise `something` will be used.

See [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization) for more information on JMeter properties

Comment: Thanks. This is not the answer I was hoping for, but it does explain why I'm having trouble.

Comment: can you tell me how to give default value as null?

Comment: @variable >  ${__P(tokenSetOnCommandLine,null)}